# How to retrieve a StringBuilder Line Count?

Tags: c#, .net, stringbuilder

I have a `StringBuilder` instance where I am doing numerous `sb.AppendLine("test");` for example.

How do I work out how many lines I have?

I see the class has `.Length` but that tells me how many characters in all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered counting the line breaks?

Comment: Only issue with counting line breaks is that StringBuilder does not have find/index-of methods - you need to either use Chars indexed property or to counting in resultant string (ToString()). Both can be inefficient if you need the line count repeatedly.

Comment: Jon, there are a number of very obvious solutions to this; could you give context to explain why these solutions aren't viable for you?

Comment: I only need it once. However I have also realised that I need to insert a line at a certain point but can't see where to do that

Comment: I like the way some of the more basic questions generate a lot feedback on SO. Amazing what tidbits you can learn and use elsewhere

Comment: Since there were no really great solutions offered to this old question, I'll throw in this which I just used (tossing out the StringBuilder I was using):

List<string> text = new List<string>();

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Sorted by efficiency:

1. Counting your AppendLine() calls
2. Calling IndexOf() in a loop
3. Using Regex
4. Using String.Split()

The last one is extraordinary expensive and generates *lots* of garbage, don't use.

Comment: I think option #1 can lead to errors, since it doesn't guarantee that the counted AppendLine() calls will truly match the real count of newlines.  The other options make eminent sense.

Comment: Meh, newlines do not fall from the sky.  But yes, efficiency is risking maintainability here.

Comment: they may not fall from the sky but they can come from `Environment.NewLine`, `\r\n`, `\n`, or even from content that is passed to one of the other methods.

Answer (score 27):

You could wrap `StringBuilder` with your own class that would keep a count of lines as they are added or could the number of '\n' after your builder is full.

```
Regex.Matches(builder.ToString(), Environment.NewLine).Count
```

Comment: i guess you meant Regex.Matches(builder.ToString(), Environment.NewLine).Count; because Match() returns only one match.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a wrapper class do the following:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    private StringBuilder strBuild = null;
    private int count = 0;
    public Wrapper(){
        strBuild = new StringBuilder();
    }
    public void AppendLine(String toAppendParam){
        strBuild.AppendLine(toAppendParam);
        count++;
    }
    public StringBuilder getStringBuilder(){
        return strBuild;
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed your code formatting, but you may want to change this to be more idiomatic to C# rather than Java.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sb.ToString().Split(System.Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()).Length;
```

Comment: Umm... this code double-counts the lines... for example 3 lines of sb.AppendLine("a"); will result in 7, not 3...!

Comment: @code4life Yes (of course depending on the `Length` of the `NewLine` string on the system in question).

Comment: This will not count the lines but the line break characters used. For Linux this works but Windows uses `\r\n`. If this answer should really count the lines on all machines, just remove `.ToCharArray()`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to search for the number of occurences of \n in the string.

UPDATE:
One way could be to split on the newline character and count the number of elements in the array as follows:

```
sb.ToString().Split('\n').length;
```

Comment: Will surely work but not a good solution if you need line count repeatedly. Of course, Jon hasn't mentioned if he wants it one time or many times.

Comment: @VninayC - yes, it was an idea off the top of my head on how to do it, I didn't like it from the outset as you've got to do a ToString() to do anything at all.  Definitely if you wanted to do it multiple times wrapping it up in something that kept a count itself would be best.

Comment: Unless you're on an old mac where the newline is '\r'

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** [What Gabe said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636357/how-to-retrieve-a-stringbuilder-line-count/3636622#comment3821753_3636622)

> b.ToString().Count(c => c =='\n') would work here too, and might not
>   be much less efficient (aside from creating a separate copy of the
>   string!).

---

<strike>A better way, faster than creating a string from the StringBuilder and splitting it (or creating the string and `regex`ing it), is to look into the StringBuilder and count the number of `'\n'` characters there in.</strike>

The following extension method will enumerate through the characters in the string builder, you can then linq on it until to your heart is content.

```
    public static IEnumerable<char> GetEnumerator(this StringBuilder sb)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; i++)
            yield return sb[i];
    }
```

... used here, count will be 4

```
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        b.AppendLine("Hello\n");
        b.AppendLine("World\n");

        int lineCount = b.GetEnumerator().Count(c => c =='\n');
```

Comment: `b.ToString().Count(c => c =='\n')` would work here too, and might not be much less efficient (aside from creating a separate copy of the string!).

Comment: @Gabe: I should have known `b.ToString().Count(c => c =='\n')` takes about 2/3 the time my enumerator does.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use String.Split(), you will need to split the string with some options.  Like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("this");
    sb.AppendLine("is");
    sb.AppendLine("a");
    sb.AppendLine("test");

    // StringSplitOptions.None counts the last (blank) newline 
    // which the last AppendLine call creates
    // if you don't want this, then replace with 
    // StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
    var lines = sb.ToString().Split(
        new string[] { 
            System.Environment.NewLine }, 
        StringSplitOptions.None).Length;

    Console.WriteLine("Number of lines: " + lines);

    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This results in:

`Number of lines: 5`

Answer (score 1):

Derive your own line counting `StringBuilder` where `AppendLine` ups an internal line count and provides a method to get the value of line count.

Answer (score 0):

Do a regex to count the number of line terminators (ex: \r\n) in the string. Or, load the strings into a text box and do a line count but thats the hack-ey way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

You can split string bulider data into String[] array and then use String[].Length for number of lines.

something like as below:

```
String[] linestext = sb.Split(newline)
Console.Writeline(linetext.Length)
```